# How to search a directory?

Tags: linux, shell, search, directory

The Linux type is Ubuntu. I have created programmatically through a java application a directory into a Linux computer webserver. I do not know where the directory is , but I know its name. So how to search it beginning from the root directory ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find / -type d -name 'name-of-the-directory'
```

Comment: I have corrected the question title ; please upvote my question. Please.

Comment: @andy: I upvoted your question, but it's not me that downvoted it.